# Laravel XSS in URL

Tags: php, laravel, xss

I got a scan report from my QA team with 500+ XSS vulnerability. I am using laravel 4.1.

Example vulnerable URL: `http://www.domain.com/section"><script>prompt(910662)</script>/article`

My application doesn's actually executes and displays the alert instead it just shows a pageNotFound error page. Then why the Acunetix Tool shows this as High level Threat of type XSS.

Do i have to return a custom error code ?

I have tried using strip_tags filter but it didn't work. The errors are still the same. Plus they can still inject something like "`javascript:alert('1')`".

Please help me in resolving these errors.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the response error from 
Code:404, Message:NotFound 
to 
Code:200, Message:Invalid request.

The above resolved the XSS alerts i was getting from the vulnerability scanner.